# SwiftUI NavigationView on the iPad Pro

Tags: swiftui

I use the Apple SwiftUI tutorial code. Then I set the previewDevice to iPad Pro (12.9-inch). But the preview has something wrong.
Does anyone know where the problem is?

[image: SwiftUI preview issue]

Comment: Have you tried sliding out the "drawer" on the left side (swipe in from left)? In portrait mode an iPad auto hides the master view in a master-detail UI.

Comment: wow~ thank you for your reminder.
Btw, can I set the navigation view like the iphone?

Comment: I'm not sure. I have not figured out a way to do that. But I ran into your issue while experimenting and thought I could help with that!

Comment: As of Beta 4 there is a new property on NavigationView that allows you to lay out the master-detail in two columns: `.navigationViewStyle(.doubleColumn)`

Comment: Look here -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/66665464/7278926

Answer (score 102):

You can override the default splitView used on iPad, by having the NavigationView display the same stacked view you see on iPhone, by setting 
    `.navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())`

Quite helpful during development and debugging, and when you have not developed the detailedView() yet.

Comment: I want to see the detail view I'm working on in my preview, so this is exactly what I needed to add to my `PreviewProvider`. Thanks!

Comment: when I use this on iOS 15, navigation bar becomes invisible in certain cases, without this modifier it doesn't, but then I have the wrong navigation style on iPad (default instead of stack - which I want to use).

Comment: iOS 16
.navigationViewStyle(.stack)

Answer (score 42):

In my case what make the difference was using `StackNavigationViewStyle` and no padding were needed.

```
NavigationView {
  ...
}
.navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
```

Comment: for me too, thanks for this tip, it was what solved my problem

Answer (score 14):

Slide the drawer from the left side of the screen.

If you would to remove the drawer and have it constant, you can do the following (note the padding is what makes the drawer constant):

```
.navigationViewStyle(DefaultNavigationViewStyle())
        .padding(0)
```

or

```
.navigationViewStyle(DoubleColumnNavigationViewStyle())
        .padding(0)
```

Note: This does not currently work perfectly with all iPad views. For example on the iPad 9.7in, the above padding(0) would make the portrait view have the list, but the landscape view have the slideout. This would also not work correctly on the iPad 12.9in. If you don't have the padding included, it works in landscape on the 9.7in, but not in portrait.

Answer (score 8):

It looks like the master view (the one on the left) is hidden on iPads running iOS 13 by design. The master view is there, you can pull it out from the left edge of the screen.

Unfortunately, there is currently no API to opt-out of this behavior other than applying a non-zero padding for the `leading` edge:

```swift
var body: some View {
    GeometryReader { geometry in
        NavigationView {
            self.content
        }.padding(.leading, self.leadingPadding(geometry))
    }
}

private func leadingPadding(_ geometry: GeometryProxy) -> CGFloat {
    if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad {
        // A hack for correct display of the SplitView in SwiftUI on iPad
        return geometry.size.width < geometry.size.height ? 0.5 : -0.5
    }
    return 0
}
```

Comment: This looked really promising, but doesn't work for Plus-sized iPhones in landscape. (The master view still needs to be dragged in manually)

Answer (score 5):

You have embedded your body in NavigationView.In iPad,you have to slide the drawer from left side to view your content view.

Remove NavigationView and observe the behaviour

To override default behaviour, use below code

`NavigationView {
    ...
}
.navigationViewStyle(DoubleColumnNavigationViewStyle())
.padding()`

Comment: I notice that, in the standard view style, the detail view in the OP's mentioned tutorial runs underneath the list view, making it useless.  Using double-column style restricts the detail view to the exposed screen area, which is what the view design is expecting.

Answer (score 3):

### Correct Solution!

All the answers here were unhelpful as they were missing a vital view to be shown before a selection has been made in the NavigationView. This is necessary on iPad if both views are to be visible at the start!

To use `.columns` in `NavigationView`, we should provide a default Detail view that is to be shown, when nothing has been selected, i.e. `WordView("")`.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var words: [String] = []
    @State private var selected: String?
    @FocusState private var isFocused: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(selection: $selected) {
                ForEach(words) { word in
                    NavigationLink(tag: word, selection: $selected) {
                        WordView(word)
                    } label: {
                        Text(word)
                    }
                }
                .task {
                    isFocused = true
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Words")
            .navigationViewStyle(.columns)

            // Detail view shown when nothing has been selected
            WordView("")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using the code provided by nalexn I came up with this as the solution.

As commented by matthew in the same post iPhones in landscape mode will still cause the drawer to be hidden thus, using `StackNavigationViewStyle()` is more suitable for iPhone whilst for iPad it will use the `DoubleColumnNavigationViewStyle()`

```
    var body: some View {
    GeometryReader{ geo in
      if (UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad){
        NavigationView{
          self.makeContents()
        }.navigationViewStyle(DoubleColumnNavigationViewStyle())
          .padding(.leading, geo.size.width < geo.size.height ? 0.25 : 0)
      }else{
        NavigationView{
          self.makeContents()
        }.navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
      }
    }
  }
```

Hope this helps anyone that comes to this post after me :D

Answer (score 1):

**Use this**

```
    NavigationView {}.navigationViewStyle(.stack)
```

Comment: This is a duplicate answer and does not provide any new information. The top voted answer by Sondergaard has this method, and Gurjinder Singh has updated the method for the most recent OS.

Comment: I mentioned this because in their one-line code, I was not able to understand do I need to write this line inside or outside the block of NavigationView. So, clarifying that thing I wrote the above answer....