# Doesn't the iPad-simulator launch NavigationView App in Xcode 11 beta 5?

Tags: ipad, ios-simulator, swiftui, xcode11

I am working on a universal-app and want to test it with the iPad-simulator in Xcode beta 5, but it shows me only a white screen. With the iPhone-simulator the app runs.

I have uninstalled Xcode and macOS Catalina completely and reinstalled both, but it doesn't help

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Text("This is a great app")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: possibly duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57049384/swiftui-navigationview-on-the-ipad-pro

Answer (score 2):

I believe if you swipe in from the lefthand side of your screen it may appear.

Comment: also add .navigationViewStyle(.stack) which works for now but is deprecated.