# NavigationView only shows Back button in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I just create a swiftUI project and type this code on CntentView.swift. But the result is this image below. It was the same when I tried to run it on a real machine.
Why?

[image: NavigationView only shows Back button]

Environment:
Xcode Version 12.2(12B45b),

---

This is code of "Test13App.swift". Not edited any line.
[image]

---

Thank you very much for your comments. Since I only have iPad pro (and not have iPhone), I just knew this is a default behaviour of iPad split view now by your comments. Adding .navigationViewStyle(DefaultNavigationViewStyle()) right after NavigationView solved the problem like this
[SwiftUI NavigationView on the iPad Pro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57049384/swiftui-navigationview-on-the-ipad-pro)

Sorry and Thanks very much!

Comment: It doesn't look normal. Can you share the code in `Test13App.swift`?

Comment: It is default navigation view style for iPad, split view - left sidebar is hidden. What did you expect?

Comment: Thanks for help. I added the image of Test13App.swift. And , oh, this is the normal behavior of iPad split view...? I expect, a text shown in the middle of the screen on iPad too.

Comment: Cuneyt, Asperi, Thank you! Solved the problem! I add .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationStyle()) and working same as iPhone!

Answer (score 4):

If you want to change the style of your NavigationView on iPad making it similar to iPhone, you could use the:

`.navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())`

option in your `NavigationView`.

Like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            Text("prova")
        }
        .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When focused on both iPhone and iPad devices some developer's missing set the navigationview style type.

[Set the NavigationView Style](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KUS74.png)